# как сохранять данные даже если перезайти с другого браузера

Tags: php, html, input, текст

есть вот такой код:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="first" />
<input type="submit" name="ok_go" value="GO" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ok_go'])){
$first_var = $_POST['first'];
$first_var = trim($first_var);
if(empty($first_var)) echo 'Пусто';
else {
echo 'Вы ввели: <b>', $first_var, '</b>';
}
}
?>
```

ввожу в страницу текст, показывает вы ввели (мой текст)
вот только после перезахода через другой браузер не сохраняет что я вводил.
Как сделать так чтобы введеный мною текст сохранился даже после обновления страницы?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$first_var = null;
if(isset($_POST['ok_go'])){
    $first_var = $_POST['first'];
    $first_var = trim($first_var);
    if(empty($first_var)) echo 'Пусто'; else {
        echo 'Вы ввели: <b>', $first_var, '</b>';
    }
}
?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="first" value="<?= $first_var ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="ok_go" value="GO" />
</form>
```

Comment: Вам стоить добавить несколько слов хотя бы.. Например, что php надо добавить перед формой, как минимум.

Comment: Это не работает, в другом браузере ничего не показывает

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();

$first_var = null;
if(isset($_POST['ok_go'])){
    $first_var = $_POST['first'];
    $first_var = trim($first_var);

    if(empty($first_var)) {
        echo 'Пусто'; 
    } else {
        $_SESSION['var'] = $first_var;
        echo 'Вы ввели: <b>', $first_var, '</b>';
    }
}
?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="first" value="<?= isset($_SESSION['var']) ? $_SESSION['var'] : '' ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="ok_go" value="GO" />
</form>
```

Comment: с другого браузера не сохраняет не показывает введеный текст

Comment: а с другого браузера вам и не покажет) как вы себе это вообще представляете ?

Comment: что бы показывало в другом браузере, вам необходимо результат куда-то записывать, в файл или базу данных, потом считывать его и выводить )

Comment: я в php не шарю, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: ну собственно ответ у вас есть)

Answer (score 0):

Никак не сделать. Вся авторизация основана на том, что браузер тебя "запоминает". В браузере есть cookies - это такое хранилище данных, в которое ты с сервера можешь дать команду на запись. В следующем запросе браузер тебе пошлет ту инфу, которую ты ему сказал сохранить. Так ты поймешь с каким пользователем имеешь дело.

Можно на одном браузере пользователю показать специальную ссылку, скопировав её и вставив в другом браузере он сможет авторизоваться. Но это очень не безопасно.